# How to add a dns record to a free url from freenom.com for connecting my domain to firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to setup a custom domain for a firebase project hosting and I have got a free subscription url (ending with .tk) from freenom.com. How do I verify my url and is it even possible to connect to a url ending with .tk

I found a DNS management section on the freenom site and even added the DNS value successfully but firebase is not verifying it. What am I doing wrong?
Screenshot url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpmZx.png

Comment: Maybe you are looking for adding your project to a custom domain did you give this a try?? [Click me](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry the process takes upto 12 to 24hrs and I was a little impatient, but the dns record was finally verified and my site went online.